# Problemas numa list - Ionic

Tags: ionic, ionic3, ionic2, arraylist

Bem, estou desenvolvendo um app com ionic e firebase. Está tudo ocorrendo dentro do esperado, porém, quando tento trazer os dados para edição, os dados ficam todos em uma coluna da lista, fiz várias pesquisas mas não encontrei uma maneira de arrumar. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

método que grava no vetor as informações. TS:

```
if (this.vetCarrinho.indexOf(element) === -1) {
   this.vetCarrinho.push(element);
```

Html :

```
  <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let element of vetCarrinho"> 
          {{element}}
          <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deleteProduto(element)" item-end>
            <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
          </button>      

        </ion-item>   
       </ion-list>
```

Comment: Eu não entendi o: "ficam todos em uma coluna da lista"? Não ficou claro o que você quer fazer ou mostrar.

Comment: Na lista da tela do app, ele fica : Celular,Celular. Mas o correto seria : 
coluna 1: Celular
coluna 2: Celular

Comment: qual atributos(colunas) tem no element?

Comment: element = this.pedido.produto, que seria o produto escolhido no ion-select

Comment: qual é o resultado que aparece se você der um console.log(vetCarrinho) ?

Comment: exatamente assim:  ["     celular      "]. Com vários espaços em branco antes e depois do elemento

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86452/discussion-between-cassio-alves-and-leonardo-sartori).